# Why does unsubscribe cancels current concatMap which is performing http request?

Tags: angular, file-upload, rxjs, rxjs6

This is my code:

```
// showing code of FileUploadService
private uploadFilesSubscription?: Subscription;
... 

// end upload of files
public stop(): void {
  this.uploadFilesSubscription?.unsubscribe();
}

// start upload of files
public start(): void {

   const uploadFiles$: Observable<FileResponseModel> = from(this.filesToUpload)
  .pipe(
    concatMap((f: FileModel, index: number): Observable<any> => {
      this.fileUploadInProgress.next(f);

      return this.documentService.createFile(f)
        .pipe(
          // continue if one of the files failed to upload
          // max POST size reached, .....
          catchError((error: WebApiErrorModel): Observable<any> => {
            this.currentFileUploadFailed.next(error.errors);

            return of('continue');
          })
        );
    })
  );

this.uploadFilesSubscription = uploadFiles$.subscribe({
  next: (r: FileResponseModel) => {
    console.log('next');
  },
  error: (error: WebApiErrorModel): void => {
    console.log('error occured');
  },
  complete: (): void => {
    console.log('Completed ok');
    this.attemptToUploadAllFilesCompleted.next();
  }
});
```

Everything works as it should, except when user wants to navigate away from current page,  we must cancel pending files for uploading.

For this I used canDeactivate method in routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: '',
  canActivateChild: [CanActivatePage],
  children: [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'documents', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'all-files', component: DocumentsHomeComponent, canDeactivate: [CanDeactivatePage] },
    { path: 'all-files/:id', component: DocumentsHomeComponent },
  ]
}
];
```

What is interesting to me is, that if I call unsubscribe, current POST request is canceled as well. It looks like a concatMap is cancelled as well. I'm staying inside angular spa application.

Shouldn't unsubscribe cancel all pending operators that are in pipe queue? Why doesn't concatMap finish and then stops fetching new data from 'from' array.

I thought that at least current http request completes (ok or fails) and then all next reqeusts are stopped.

[image]

Comment: Observables emit data only if there's at least a subscribed element. As far as the HTTP request is handled by an Observable, the unsubscribe causes the request to be cancelled. In fact, the unsubscribe is not meant to not execute the piped operators, but to handle or not the emitted data (even from the source, in your case the HTTP request)

Comment: @AndreaAlhena can you point me to some documentation stating this or should I just see the source code.

Comment: see https://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html => A “cold” Observable, on the other hand, waits until an observer subscribes to it before it begins to emit items, and so such an observer is guaranteed to see the whole sequence from the beginning. <= HttpClient uses, in fact, cold observables.

Comment: So we can say that by design, if some observable is in progress, if unsubscribe is called in the middle, it's immediately canceled.

Comment: @AndreaAlhena still not sure how does this unsubscrie event cancels current emit.